# Print javascript using R?

Tags: r, printing

I would like to produce a text file so an engineer can run the java script. It has a header (top portion) that never changes like below (snippet).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

      var myChart = new Chart.Bubble('myChartContainer', {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
```

After this chunk will be my R analysis output. So far this is what I tried (very manual but doesn't work, regardless). I tried paste(), cat() too but it didn't work either.

```
print("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"")
```

Is there any way to plant this chunk of code nicely in text file using R?

Comment: You can literally just copy and paste the "header" lines into a string variable in `R`.  Just make sure to escape any quotes and special characters with `\\`.

Comment: There was a great quote floating around:  Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet

Comment: haha, I edited my question. yes, java and javascript are different. After I saw the Ricardo's comment, now I feel like to reedit my edited question back! btw, it is a great quote =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy and paste the info.  The only problem is escaping the special characters.  So use `readLines` which will escape them for you.

```
headerInfo <- paste(readLines(file("clipboard")), collapse="\n")

cat(headerInfo)


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quote marks so that R doesn't think that the string ends after `PUBLIC`.

The backslash `\` is used to escape characters, E.g:

```
print("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"")
```

And if your string has a backslash, you need to put two backslashes in the print function.